# Proof that Peano Axioms is a theory with equality (according to Mendelson book)

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I'm reading Elliott Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic". There is a statement with a proof that $S$ (Peano Arithmetic) is a first-order theory with equality. I am not sure whether I understand the reasoning of the proof correctly.

The proof is very short, it reiterates several simpler statements about properties of $S$ and uses a proposition which says that a theory that satisfies some particular requirements, is a first order theory with equality. As I understand, the idea is that by virtue of those properties, $S$ satisfies the hypothesis of the said proposition.

My question is that I don't see why some of the properties that are reiterated are needed to satisfy the hypothesis of the proposition.

That's the quotation of the relevant part from the book:

Corollary 3.3

> S is a theory with equality
> Proof
> By Proposition 2.25, this reduces to parts (a)-(e), (i), (k) and (o) of proposition 3.2, and (S2')

Proposition 2.25

> Let $K$ be a theory in which (A6) holds and the following are true:
> a. Schema (A7) holds for all atomic wfs $\mathcal{B}(x, x)$ such that no function letters or individual constants occur in $\mathcal{B}(x, x)$ and $\mathcal{B}(x, y)$ comes from $\mathcal{B}(x, x)$ by replacing exactly one occurence of $x$ by $y$.
> b. $\vdash x = y \Rightarrow 
> f^n_j(z_1, \ldots, z_n) = f^n_j (w_1, \ldots, w_n)$, where $f^n_j$ is any function letter of $K$, $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ are variables, and $f^n_j(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ arises from $f^n_j(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ by replacing exactly one occurrence of $x$ by $y$.
> Then $K$ is a theory with equality.

Proposition 3.2

> For any terms $t, s, r,$ the following wfs are theorems of $S$:
>
> a. $t = t$
> b. $t = r \Rightarrow r = t$
> c. $t = r \Rightarrow (r = s \Rightarrow t = s)$
> d. $r = t \Rightarrow (s = t \Rightarrow r = s)$
> e. $t = r \Rightarrow (t + s = r + s)$
> i. $t = r \Rightarrow (s + t = s + r)$
> k. $t = r \Rightarrow (t * s = r * s)$
> o. $t = r \Rightarrow (s * t = s * r)$

(S2')

> For any terms $t, s, r$ of $\mathcal{L}_A$, the following wfs are theorems of $S$:
> (S2') $t = r \Rightarrow t' = r'$

Where aforementioned (A6) and (A7) are:

> (A6) $(\forall x_1) x_1 = x_1$
> (A7) $x = y \Rightarrow (\mathcal{B}(x, x) \Rightarrow \mathcal{B}(x, y))$

As I understand,

3.2 (a) ensures (A6) via Gen
3.2 (e)-(o) and (S2') are all possible instances of the conclusion in the implication of the 2.25b given that $S$ has only three functions: $'$, $+$, $*$.

what is left over, 2.25a should also be satisfied by $S$.

As I understand, $S$ has two atomic wff:
$\mathcal{B_1}(z1, z1): z1 = z2$
$\mathcal{B_2}(z2, z2): z1 = z2$

and they should be yielding the following instances to consider in (A7):
$\mathcal{B_1}(z1, w1): w1 = z2$
$\mathcal{B_2}(z2, w1): z1 = w1$

so conditions to hold should be:
$z1 = w1 \Rightarrow (z1 = z2 \Rightarrow w1 = z2)$
$z2 = w1 \Rightarrow (z1 = z2 \Rightarrow z1 = w1)$

All of this seems obscure, I'm not sure that I understand the last part correctly. What exactly do we need to satisfy an 2.25a) in this case? How do 3.2 (b) - (c) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prop.2.25 is made of two sub-cases : (a) excludes function letters and individual constants, while (b) applies to functions.

$0$ is a constant, while $',+,\times$ are functions.

Thus, to prove case (a) we need the properties regarding atomic formulas with $=$ only, i.e. 3.2 (a)-(d).

As you correctly said, from 3.2 (a) : $t=t$, using Gen we prove axiom (A6) : $\forall x (x=x)$.

3.2 (b) is necessary to rewrite (c) as : $r=t \Rightarrow (r=s \Rightarrow t=s)$.

Now, the formula is of "form" $r=t \Rightarrow (\mathcal B(r,s) \Rightarrow \mathcal B(t,s))$, where the atomic $\mathcal B(t,s)$ (that is $(t=s)$) comes from $\mathcal B(r,s)$ (i.e. $(r=s)$) by replacing exactly one occurence of $r$ by $t$.

The same for 3.2 (d) : using (b) we get : $t=r \Rightarrow (s=t \Rightarrow s=r)$, which is of "form" : $t=r \Rightarrow (\mathcal B(t,s) \Rightarrow \mathcal B(r,s))$, where the atomic $\mathcal B(t,s)$ is $(s=t)$.

In order to prove 2.25 (b) we need 3.2 (e) and (i), that take care of $+$, according to the fact that the substitution ($t=r$) applies to the left of the function symbol (i.e. $t+s=r+s$) or to the right (i.e. $s+t=s+r$).

The same for managing $\times$, that needs 3.2 (k) and (o).

Finally, (S2') takes care of the unary functipon symbol $'$ (the *successor*).

---

*Note* : regarding 3.2 (d) we have :

1) $t=r$ --- assumed [a]

2) $t=r ⇒ r=t$ --- 3.2. (b)

3) $r=t$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

4) $r=t ⇒ (s=t ⇒ r=s)$ --- 3.2 (d)

5) $(s=t ⇒ r=s)$ --- from 3) and 4) by *MP*

6) $s=t$ --- assumed [b]

7) $r=s$ --- from 5) and 6) by *MP*

8) $r=s ⇒ s=r$ --- 3.2. (b)

9) $s=r$ --- from 7) and 8) by *MP*

10) $s=t ⇒ s=r$ --- from 6) and 9) by *DT*, discharging [b]

> 11) $t=r ⇒ (s=t ⇒ s=r)$ --- from 1) and 10) by *DT*, discharging [a].

Comment: Thank you! Do I also understand it right, that actually we would like to get $t = r \Rightarrow (s = t \Rightarrow s = r)$ from (d) and not $t = r \Rightarrow (s = t \Rightarrow r = s)$? How could it be done if it is so?